# Error code list for Tesseract? 3221225781

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm experimenting Pytesseract, and got a problem. I am running Python 3.8.2 with Tesseract 4.0.0 (Also tried with 5.0.0 and 3.0.5, same error) and Pytesseract 0.3.4 (installed with pip) on Windows 10. I can launch tesseract from cmd, as I added the Path variables as intended. The png image is literally a screenshot of a 6.

The code is very simple:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('6.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

And here is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\TestPytesseract\findNumber.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
  File "C:\Users\ilita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 356, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\Users\ilita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 359, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\ilita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 270, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ilita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 246, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (3221225781, '')
```

Couldn't find anything about this error code. Any help is welcome.

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you installed tesseract for windows? https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

Comment: Yes, I tried with 4.0.0, 5.0.0 and 3.0.5. For now, 4.0.0 is installed:
`C:\Users\ilita>tesseract -v
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
 leptonica-1.74.1
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.0) : libpng 1.6.20 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0`

Comment: Windows error code are notoriously horrible; https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/shellexecuteex-failed-code-3221225477/79634d63-44a4-46f2-b780-96e467158233

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the tesseract command in your python code

```
import pytesseract
# Set the path to Tesseract-OCR
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Also, make sure if your Windows environment variables are properly set to the path you installed the Tesseract-OCR. For me, the path to Tesseract-OCR is `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\`, so the `PATH` contains

- `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`
- `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR`

and there should be an another variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` in your environment variables, and should be set as

- `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`

Hopes that helps.